# this click event right?

Tags: jquery, events, click

select script change has change the value from DB value.

i intention that .save button click some event but

may i click .saveb button do not happen event what i do that my code?

```
 <select class="chapter form-control "><option >select</option></select>



  $(".chapter").change(function () {
        var testt=$(".testment").val();
        var old=$(".ob").val();
        var nw=$(".nb").val();
        var cha=$(this).val();
        $(".readB").css("overflow-y"," scroll");
        if (typeof old == "undefined"){
            old=null;
        }else if(typeof nw == "undefined"){
            nw=null;
        } 
        $.post("readB",{"old":old,"cha":cha,"nw":nw,"testt":testt},function(read){
            $(".readLin").remove();
            console.log(read.readB);
             for(var line in read.readB){
                 $("<p/>").text(read.readB[line].paragraph+". "+read.readB[line].paraText).addClass("readLin").appendTo(".readB");
                 }
             $("<input/>").attr("type","button").attr("value","save").appendTo(".readB").addClass("btn btn-default saveb");
        });   
    });

<script>
window.onload=function(){

    $(".saveb").click(function(){
        alert("dddd");
    });


    $(".saveb").click(function(){
        alert("yyy");
    });

}</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
$(document).on('click,'.saveb',function(){
    alert("yyy");
});
```

Your are adding the class dynamically. So you need to delegate the event using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**.

This helps you attach a event handler to elements exists or which can be added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the event after you append the element.

```
$("<input/>").attr("type","button").attr("value","save").appendTo(".readB").addClass("btn btn-default saveb");
 $(".saveb").click(function(){
    alert("dddd");
 });
```